# Center text horizontally and vertically in element that has float

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a text *Drop it here* inside a `<canvas>` so that the user knows where to drop the file.

Normally, people use `display: table-cell` and then `vertical-align` to hack in the vertical centering. In my case, I have two canvas images floating to oposite directions. When I used table-cell strategy, floating was broken.

Another problem is, that the `<canvas>` size changes as user drops file inside. The centered div therefore must be centered dynamically.

So I tried absolute positioning. This is the markup, the `canvas_container` must have `float: left/right`

```
   <div class="canvas_container left">
     <div class="canvas_wrap">
       <canvas id="original" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
       <div class="dropzone first">Drop it here!</div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
  /** Every canvas can only get half of the screen */
   div.canvas_container {
     max-width: 50%;
     width: 50%;
   }
   /**The inner canvas container should center the other elements **/
   div.canvas_container div.canvas_wrap {
     position: relative;
     height: 100%;
     display: inline-block;
     /*vertical-align: middle; */
   }

   div.canvas_container canvas {
      display: block;
      /*position:absolute;*/
      top:0px;
      left: 0px;
   }

   /**This div should be centered**/
   div.canvas_container div.first {
     display: block;
     margin: auto;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
   }
```

Why does not the `top: 0; bottom: 0` cause vertical centering? And why does `margin: auto` fail to center the div horizontally?

```css
   canvas {
     max-width: 100%;
     background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABmJLR0QAkwCTAJP5tiLoAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3goVFxMCXx/9uAAAAB1pVFh0Q29tbWVudAAAAAAAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBkLmUHAAAAKUlEQVQY02OcPHnyfwY04OTkhC7EwMRAJBhAhYxXr17F8My+ffuGpGcA6xQJSXdOZ30AAAAASUVORK5CYII=); 

   }
   div#canvases {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0px;
   }
   /** Every canvas can only get half of the screen */
   div.canvas_container {
     max-width: 50%;
     width: 50%;
   }
   /**The inner canvas container should center the other elements **/
   div.canvas_container div.canvas_wrap {
     position: relative;
     height: 100%;
     display: inline-block;
     /*vertical-align: middle; */
   }
   
   div.canvas_container canvas {
      display: block;
      /*position:absolute;*/
      top:0px;
      left: 0px;
   }
   
   /**This div should be centered**/
   div.canvas_container div.first {
     display: block;
     margin: auto;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
   }
   
   div.canvas_container.left {
     float: left;
     
   }
   div.canvas_container.right {
     float: right;         
     text-align: right;
   }
   div.canvas_container.right div.canvas_wrap {
     margin-left: 0px;         
   }
```

```html
     <div id="canvases">
       <div class="canvas_container left">
         <div class="canvas_wrap">
           <canvas id="original" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
           <div class="dropzone first">Drop it here!</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="canvas_container right">
         <div class="canvas_wrap">
           <canvas id="result" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABmJLR0QAkwCTAJP5tiLoAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3goVFxMCXx/9uAAAAB1pVFh0Q29tbWVudAAAAAAAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBkLmUHAAAAKUlEQVQY02OcPHnyfwY04OTkhC7EwMRAJBhAhYxXr17F8My+ffuGpGcA6xQJSXdOZ30AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
div#canvases {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
/** Every canvas can only get half of the screen */

div.canvas_container {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
/**The inner canvas container should center the other elements **/

div.canvas_container div.canvas_wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  /*vertical-align: middle; */
}
div.canvas_container canvas {
  display: block;
  /*position:absolute;*/
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
/**This div should be centered**/

div.canvas_container div.first {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
div.canvas_container.left {
  float: left;
}
div.canvas_container.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
div.canvas_container.right div.canvas_wrap {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.first p {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.first p:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(156, 156, 156);
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto auto;
  background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
  width: 115px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvases">
  <div class="canvas_container left">
    <div class="canvas_wrap">
      <canvas id="original" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
      <div class="dropzone first">
        <p>Drop it here!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="canvas_container right">
    <div class="canvas_wrap">
      <canvas id="result" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

First of all, I've wrapped the text `Drop it here!` with `<p></p>` tags and then applied the following styles to that `<p>` tag:

```
.first p {
      display: table-cell;
      height: 150px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 150px;
      text-align: center;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To apply a background behind the `Drop it here!` text, I've styled the `.first p:before` like this:

```
.first p:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(156, 156, 156);
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto auto;
  background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
  width: 115px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: It has a big disadvantage - I can't apply any background to it, because it's as big as the canvas. Would another wrapper layer solve it?

Comment: You want to apply a background to the text?

Comment: I wanted it to look like this: http://pbrd.co/ZOkP5t And though the `<canvas>` has initally width 150px, it scales depending on what does user drop in. Is it possible to center it anyway?

Comment: @TomášZato If you only want to center it and not vertically align it then you can only use `text-align: center` like this: `.first p { text-align: center; }`.

Comment: I want to align it and center it vertically - I really wish it could always appear in the middle of the canvas regardless of canvas size. Centering in CSS has became a nightmare for me.

Comment: @TomášZato Please check my updated answer. Using that you can add create a background behind the text. I believe you can use that until you find a better solution.